# Properties file not found - how to locate it as resource?

Tags: java

I have a properties file at location (from netbeans project explorer)

```
-MyTest
    +Web Pages
    +Source Packages
    -Test Packages
        -<default package>
            +Env.properties     <---- Here it is
        +com.mycomp.gts.test
        +com.mycomp.gts.logintest
        .....
        ....
```

Now when I am trying to find this file using code

```
InputStream propertiesInputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Env.properties");
ENV.load(propertiesInputStream);
```

Its throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: This answer may helps in your case as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8854824/122442

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use the class as a reference to load the resource, because the resource path is *not* relative to the class. Use the class loader instead:

```
InputStream propertiesInputStream = getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("Env.properties");
ENV.load(propertiesInputStream);
```

Or alternatively, you can use the context class loader of the current thread:

```
InputStream propertiesInputStream = Thread.currentThread()
    .getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Env.properties");
ENV.load(propertiesInputStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String basePath = PropertiesUtil.class.getResource("/").getPath();
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(basePath + "Env.properties");
pros.load(in);
```

Good luck:)

Comment: it refer to any class is ok.

Comment: build failed: cannot find symbol class PropertiesUtil

Comment: replace PropertiesUtil with any class in classpath, my solution is absolutely OK.

Comment: at run time basePath is /build/web/WEB-INF/classes/ but my properties file is in /build/test/classes/

Answer (score 1):

Try to get absolute path with:

```
String absolute = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toExternalForm();
```

You can print out the string `absolute` and try to substring it to your path of your properties file.

Answer (score 0):

The below code reads a property file stored within the resources folder of a Maven project.

```java
InputStream inputStream = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/filename.properties");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
    
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(reader);
  
} catch (IOException ioException) {
    ioException.printStackTrace();
}
```